# iPhone preferences (NSUserDefaults) not working, keys always return nil

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I made some preferences in my Settings.bundle that show up fine in the Settings app.   However my settings always return nil when I read them back.  I know I need to set a default value on first startup.  But even after that and going to the settings menu (which should also set the default values) - when I read them back I always get nil.

Even when I set the default and read it back immediately I get nil!

```
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YES" forKey:@"displaySunTimes"];
  [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
  [defaults synchronize];

  bool test =[defaults boolForKey:@"displaySunTimes"];
  NSLog(@" Value %@", test);
```

Here's the beginning of my root.plist

```xml
<dict>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
            <dict>
                    <key>Type</key>
                    <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
                    <key>Title</key>
                    <string>Display Sunrise / Sunset times for your location.</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                    <key>Type</key>
                    <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
                    <key>Title</key>
                    <string>Sunrise / Sunset</string>
                    <key>Key</key>
                    <string>displaySunTimes</string>
                    <key>DefaultValue</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>TrueValue</key>
                    <string>YES</string>
                    <key>FalseValue</key>
                    <string>NO</string>
            </dict>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store a BOOL then use:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"displaySunTimes"];
```

In order to retrieve it from defaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"displaySunTimes"];
```

**EDIT**:
Change the `NSLog(@" Value %@", test);` to `NSLog(@" Value %i", test);` (BOOL is not an object).
In addition, use `BOOL` instead of `bool`.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(  how strange.  It's as if the "dislaySunTimes" key isn't getting set right.

Comment: Prefer C99's bool. BOOL is a signed char.

Answer (score 1):

It helps if you understand the difference between `@"YES"`, `[NSNumber numberWithBOOL:YES]`, and `YES`.

In this case, it's returning "NO" (`(BOOL)0`), not "nil" (`(id)0`). Use `objectForKey:` if you want to know if something is stored at all. In this case, you are storing the NSString @"YES" and trying to read it as a bool; I refer you to the docs for boolForKey:

> If a boolean value is associated with defaultName in the user defaults, that value is returned. Otherwise, NO is returned.

A string is not a boolean, so @"YES" becomes NO. Try something like this:

```
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBOOL:YES] forKey:@"displaySunTimes"];
```

Answer (score 0):

- A little odd to be using a String to represent a bool value.  <s>Try `[NSNumber numberWithBOOL: YES]` instead.</s> As others pointed out (and I'd forgotten), use the `boolForKey:` and `setBool:forKey:` APIs on NSUserDefaults.
- When I've run into something like this it is because I somehow managed to push the wrong defaults value into the defaults database.   Are you sure you don't have a default value from a previous run sticking around?

Registration defaults are the default value to use when a value has not been previously set.

---

Unless the app and all data is being deleted between each run, then this still sounds exactly like you have a default value already set and the registration default isn't overriding it (correct behavior).

Try manually setting the default to some other value and synchronizing.

Note also that `synchronize` is completely orthogonal to registration defaults.

Comment: Still didn't with that bool.  Am sure I don't have anything in preferences, I deleted the app and reinstalled and tried again.  My root.plist is above.